# Tensorflow installed by Keras overrides Tensorflow-GPU Installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I am having a slight issue while trying to make use of **keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer** class. I've recently installed Tensorflow-GPU and everything worked perfectly fine until I tried to install Keras.

When I installed Keras using Anaconda, I saw that it installed Tensorflow 1.3 as well. Thing is, it did not DOWNGRADE previously installed Tensorflow-GPU version. Now that I try to run my python code, nothing happens, here is screenshot (Note: there should be some printing and processing happening):

[image]

When I try to run python shell and check for Tensorflow version, I get the one that Keras installed. So I tried to install Tensorflow-GPU again, but it saids that all requirements have been satisfied.

How do I get the functionality I need from Keras, but still keep my Tensorflow-GPU installed? And why is my code not even trying to run even on Tensorflow 1.3 that Keras installed with it?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by using `pip install keras` instead of `conda install -c anaconda keras`. By using pip I am only installing keras, and not dependencies that Anaconda includes with it.